# Conditional Styling of Map Results in Salesforce LWC Table

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, conditional, style

I am trying to change the font color of a custom field values displayed in a table. This is based on a condition wherein if this custom field's value is less than a specific amount, it will display said value in red font.

I have no problem in displaying the correct values, but each time I try to attempt to style the values, nothing changes.

**Note:** `computedValue` is the variable assigned in Apex class to get the value of the custom field named `Computed_Value__c`

Below are some portions of the codes I have problem with:

**html file**:

```
<!-- body section in html-->
<tbody>
<template if:true={actualResults}>
    <template for:each={actualResults} for:item="keyValue">
        <tr key={keyValue.key}>
            <td scope="col" style={keyValue.styleColor}>
                <div>{keyValue.value.computedValue}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </template> 
</template>
</tbody>
```

**javascript file**:

```
import getAllResult from '@salesforce/apex/SampleController.getAllResult';

export default class SampleLWC extends LightningElement {

@track actualResults = [];

//section in javascript

getAllResult()
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            let mapResult = [];
            
            var styleColor;    

            for (var key in result) {
                mapResult.push({ key: key, value: result[key] });
                        
            }
            this.actualResults = mapResult.map(e => {
                 let isLess = e.Computed_Value__c < 1000;
                 e.styleColor = isLess ? 'background-color:red' :'background- 
                 color:none';
                 return e;
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're declaring mapResult but not actually adding any objects to the array, nor adding the styleColor attribute to any of those objects:

Assuming your Apex is returning a List of records...

```
this.actualResults = [...result].map(e => {
   // You may have to "clone" each element in "result" array if you get an immutable error
   // let o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)); // replace e with o below
   let isLess = e.Computed_Value__c < 1000;
   e.styleColor = isLess ? 'background-color:red' : 'background-color:none';
   return e;
});
```

EDIT: Taking your current code all the way home
You can replace the following:

```
if (result) {
...
}
```

With:

```
if (result) {
    //let result = [{Id:'00123',Computed_Value__c:1200}, {Id:'00124',Computed_Value__c:800}];
    this.actualResults = [...result].map(e => {
        let isLess = e.Computed_Value__c < 1000;
        e.styleColor = isLess ? 'background-color:red' : 'background-color:none';
        return e;
    });
}
```

And simplify your code by using the unique SF Id as the Key:

```
<tr key={keyValue.Id}>
    <td scope="col" style={keyValue.styleColor}>
        <div>{keyValue.computedValue}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I modified my code based on your suggestion, but the result is still the same: no effect on font-colors even when the criteria is met. For this line, `this.actualResults = [...result].map(e => {` , I added `mapResult`. Is this correct?

Comment: If you are providing background color, then in html you should use `style` attribute instead of `class`. Example: `style={keyValue.styleColor}>`

Comment: @manjit5190 I modified html code to this `style={keyValue.styleColor}>` but vs code displays following : `Do not use empty rulesets`

Comment: I was able to remove above message by disabling `css.validate` to false in settings.json file. No more errors so far and was able to deploy it, but still, it does not change the background color. Hoping anyone can help me on this.

Comment: @Ertyq Thanks for the comments, I've edited my answer.  You can get rid of mapResult by using the Id of the records as the key.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Y2KBkMaktpddQ9XCMhC5) is simplified version of code which works.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <tbody>
        <template if:true={actualResults}>
            <template for:each={actualResults} for:item="keyValue">
                <tr key={keyValue.key}>
                    <td scope="col" style={keyValue.styleColor}>
                        <div>{keyValue.Computed_Value__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import {LightningElement} from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    get actualResults() {

        let result = [{
            key: 1,
            Computed_Value__c: 1200
        }, {
            key: 2,
            Computed_Value__c: 800
        }]

        return result.map(e => {
            // You may have to "clone" each element in "result" array if you get an immutable error
            // let o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)); // replace e with o below
            let isLess = e.Computed_Value__c < 1000;
            e.styleColor = isLess ? 'background-color:red' : 'background-color:green';
            return e;
        });
    }
}
```

Result

[image: Result]